# codeigniter - Config overrides set_cookie parameters

Tags: codeigniter, cookies, configuration

In my config i have set `cookie_httponly` to `true`, and now i've got a problem with `set_cookie`. All my other cookies i want to be `httponly`, which means not accessible by javascript, but there's one cookie, which i want to access via javascript. I've got one `set_cookie` function in which i've specified `httponly` to be false, but it seems that the config overrides that parameter, because the cookie still ends up as `httponly`. `set_cookie('dyn_brcr', '["'.$page.'"]', 36000000, '', '', '', '', false);`, i've also noticed that when i turn `httponly` to `false` in the config i'm still able to put the cookie to be `httponly` in `set_cookie`, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations, you've found a bug!

The [patch](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/422b8890e8b41a9ecf6644bff169c8c82fa2c82d) fixing it will be released with CodeIgniter 3.1.4.

As a temporary work-around, you can pass `0` instead of `false`.